# Read class value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vb.net

I am trying to read class value through jQuery. Here's the button code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnsaveqfdmatrix" Text="Save" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnsaveqfdmatrix_Click" />
```

Button click method:

```
Protected Sub btnsaveqfdmatrix_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(UI.Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "QfdAjax();", True)
End Sub
```

In QfdAjax() function, I am trying to loop through a table td with id #Qfd and in that those td which have `class="highlight1"`. I have a condition to check if `class="highlight1"` is there, though it is not entering in the condition. The class with highlight1 is not retaining on button click `"btnsaveqfdmatrix_Click"`.

```
function QfdAjax() {
    var custreq = [];
    $("#Qfd td").each(function () {
        if ($("#Qfd td").hasClass("highlight1")) {
            cols = $(this).closest("tr").children("td").index($(this));
        }
    });
}
```

How do I retain those td which have class="highlight1" state and then enter into condition `if ($("#Qfd td").hasClass("highlight1")) {`? Any help would be appreciated.

Table structure

```
<table class="table" id="Qfd">
    <tr>
        <td>Slitting</td>
        <td class="highlight1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does your HTML of the table look like? Which element has the ID? You said `table td with id #Qfd` if the `td` has the ID then your selector is wrong and should be `$("td#Qfd")`

Comment: @empiric table structure i have updated in the post

Comment: How is your `td` *getting* the `highlight1` class?  *"not retaining on button click"* - probably time to move away from vb.net's terrible server-side handlers and just add js `$("#btnsaveqfdmatrix").click(QfdAjax)` - *assuming* the click event *only* does `RegisterStartupString` - there may be something else happening outside the question

Comment: @freedomn-m  i am adding class in selected td on click